# We have a roll off to see

Tags: meaning

What is that means?

> Full sentence:
>   **DM and me have a roll off to see** how many rounds it
>   takes the wizard to break my grapple before he gets out.

Source - https://www.reddit.com/r/DnDGreentext/comments/83o8p7/higher_constitution_wizard_or_barbarian/

Answer (score 1):

I don’t know what it means specifically in the context of this game, but it sounds like “me” and DM are going to roll dice and compare results to determine the number of rounds referenced in the text. This is a common usage of *off*:

> [off adverb (IN COMPETITION)](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/off)
>   also -off used to form nouns referring to a situation in which two or more people or teams compete against each other to see who is the winner:
>   *the BBC series, the Great British Bake Off*
>   *Audience applause determines the winner of each dance-off.*
>   (Cambridge Dictionary)

Comment: Yeah i thought same, but then i think if "roll off" wouldn't be a separate words, but instead is a phraseing. I mean if they try just roll to see it, then there no particular reason for "off" part, i'm wrong?

Comment: It is a matter of style. As far as I know, you often separate when the words form a verb. When they form a noun or adjective, you can write it together with a hyphen, or sometimes with no space and no hyphen.

Comment: @Marader Either *will roll to see* or *have a roll off to see* works. The choice of using *roll* as a verb or a noun is purely a matter of choice.